# "Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'" not working

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I have the following java filter to had the CSP to each response for my Angular app.

```
public class FrameOptionsFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'");
    ...
```

I use this snippet to test my app:

```
    <html>
     <head>
     <title>Clickjacking Test</title>
      </head>
       <body>
        <p>Website is vulnerable to clickjacking!</p>
        <iframe src="http://localhost:4200/myapp/" width="600" height="600"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The login screen load and once I log in I can still access the app!

the response from the server:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:4200/myapp/login/jwt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The frame-ancestors CSP directive has to come from the child/iframe.
That would be the `/myapp` response.

If you want to do it the other way, on the `/myapp/login/jwt` reponse you should include `frame-src 'none';` instead

Frame-ancestors tells whoever wants to iframe *you* if they are allowed to do it, and gives the child the ability to control this